# Managing Multiple Deferreds "Gracefully"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build-up & run a set of Deferreds Ajax calls sequentially. There are a million examples online, but my requirements are slightly different than the examples I've looked at.

- The example below runs each sequentially, but doesnt return the result to the calling $.when
- How do I get the calling $.when to work?
- If you have an overall better solution than the one below...I'm open to that (as well)

**REQUIREMENTS:** I'm trying to...

- Run each ajax call separately & completely (one-at-a-time)
- If it fails, return the failed-result back to the caller's $.when
- If it is successful, run the next one ajax call
- If all are successfull, return the final result back to the caller's $.when

**WHY DID I USE A RECURSIVE CALL?:**
I needed something like a WHILE statement (to simulate sequential calls).  And...previous attempts using FOR or EACH would always runthrough the entire array regardless of pass/fail.

**CODE:**

```
// This code BUILDS the array
// This portion is working perfectly...please look at the CLICK EVENT instead
var builder = {
    autoCloseExecutableArray: function ($interactions) {
        var executables = [];
        var factory = new _factories.HtmlTemplateFactory();

        $.each($interactions, function (idx, ele) {

            // Build
            var executable = function (dfd) {

                // Elements
                var $interaction = $(ele);
                var interaction = $interaction.data('interaction');

                var $working = factory.generateStatusWorkingHtml();
                var $status = $('.status', $interaction);

                $status.empty();
                $status.append($working);

                // Action
                var filter = new _ajax.documentInteraction.models.DocumentInteractionFilter();
                filter.ContextId = interaction.DocumentId;
                filter.ContextFullname = interaction.ContextFullname;

                var query = _ajax.documentInteraction.autoClose(filter);
                query.always(function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // Animate
                    $interaction.css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
                    $interaction.stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#fff' }, 1500, function () { });
                });
                query.done(function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // SUCCESS
                    var $success = factory.generateStatusSuccessHtml();
                    $status.empty();
                    $status.append($success);

                    dfd.resolve(true);
                });
                query.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

                    // EXCEPTION
                    var $exception = factory.generateStatusExceptionHtml();
                    $status.empty();
                    $status.append($exception);

                    dfd.resolve(false);
                });
            };

            executables.push(executable);
        });

        return executables.reverse();
    }
};

// This is the CLICK EVENT for the button
var btnContinue: function (e) 
{
    try
    {
        var $interactions = $('.interaction', dictionary.$elements.analysis);
        var autoCloseExecutables = builder.autoCloseExecutableArray($interactions);

        // To Run Each Executable Sequentially (using recursion)
        // <param id='pointer'>An executable ajax-function</param>
        var recursiveWhen = function (pointer) {

            var wrapper = new $.Deferred();
            var execution = function () {
                var dfd = new $.Deferred();
                var executable = new pointer(dfd);
                return dfd.promise();
            };

            $.when(execution()).then(function (result) {

                // Fail Gracefully
                if (result === false) {
                    wrapper.resolve(result);
                    return;
                }

                // Finish Gracefully
                if (autoCloseExecutables.length == 0) {
                    wrapper.resolve(result);
                    return;
                }

                // Enqueue Next
                var next =  autoCloseExecutables.pop();
                recursiveWhen(next);
            });

            return wrapper.promise()
        };

        // Begin processing
        var autoClosePromise = autoCloseExecutables.pop();
        $.when(recursiveWhen(autoClosePromise)).then(function (result) {

            // QUESTION: Why doesn't it ever reach here?
            var stop = "";
        });
    }
    catch (exception) 
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) rather than `$.when`. If I'm not mistaken, the result of a call to `$.ajax` is close enough to a Promise to work. I'm not confident enough in that (or in replicating your code) to provide an answer.

Comment: Actually...I just figured it out.  I'm gonna leave the question up in-case folks provide a better solution.   If they don't...I will post my solution.  Thanks for the help

Comment: BTW...if "all settled" means all the functions were run...I'm not doing that.  I want it to completely-stop on the 1st fail.  The only time all should run...is when all have succeeded.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood "If it fails, return the failed-result back to the caller's $.when" as meaning it should return the failed-result, and continue on to the next query. You want `Promise.all` then.

Comment: Yeah, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#description: "Promise.all() will reject immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this...

- Gather up all Action Items
- Build an array of executable Deferred's
- Pop the first executable Deferred
- Throw 1st Deferred into a custom "Recursive When" (calls each one-at-a-time)
- When that one completes...get the next Deferred
- When all are done...trigger a 'success' event

This worked for me.

**BUILDER CODE:**
This is called in the buttons click-eventy.

```
var builder = {
    autoCloseExecutableArray: function ($interactions) {
        var executables = [];
        var factory = new _factories.HtmlTemplateFactory();

        $.each($interactions, function (idx, ele) {

            // Build
            var executable = function (dfd) {

                // Elements
                var $interaction = $(ele);
                var interaction = $interaction.data('interaction');

                var $working = factory.generateStatusWorkingHtml();
                var $status = $('.status', $interaction);

                $status.empty();
                $status.append($working);

                // Action
                var filter = new _ajax.documentInteraction.models.DocumentInteractionFilter();
                filter.ContextId = interaction.DocumentId;
                filter.ContextFullname = interaction.ContextFullname;

                var query = _ajax.documentInteraction.autoClose(filter);
                query.always(function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // Animate
                    $interaction.css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
                    $interaction.stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#fff' }, 1500, function () { });
                });
                query.done(function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // SUCCESS
                    var $success = factory.generateStatusSuccessHtml();
                    $status.empty();
                    $status.append($success);

                    dfd.resolve(true);
                });
                query.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

                    // EXCEPTION
                    var $exception = factory.generateStatusExceptionHtml();
                    $status.empty();
                    $status.append($exception);

                    dfd.resolve(false);
                });
            };

            executables.push(executable);
        });

        return executables.reverse();
    }
};
```

**BUTTON CLICK EVENT CODE:**
This does all the processing.

```
btnContinue: function (e) {

    dictionary.$elements.btnClose.addClass('disabled');
    dictionary.$elements.btnContinue.addClass('disabled');

    dictionary.$elements.lblFooterMessage.empty();
    dictionary.$elements.lblFooterMessage.removeClass('exception');

    try
    {
        var $interactions = $('.interaction', dictionary.$elements.analysis);
        var autoCloseExecutables = builder.autoCloseExecutableArray($interactions);
        var wrapper = new $.Deferred();

        // Clear All
        var $statuses = $('.status', $interactions);
        $statuses.empty();

        // Factory-Method Runs an Individual Executable (using recursion)
        // <param id='pointer'>An unprocessed Deferred</param>
        var recursiveWhen = function (pointer) {

            var execution = function () {
                var dfd = new $.Deferred();
                var executable = new pointer(dfd);
                return dfd.promise();
            };

            execution().then(function (result) {

                // Fail
                if (result === false) {
                    wrapper.resolve(result);
                    return;
                }

                // Complete
                if (autoCloseExecutables.length == 0) {
                    wrapper.resolve(result);
                    return;
                }

                // Enqueue Next
                var next =  autoCloseExecutables.pop();
                recursiveWhen(next);
            });
        };

        // Begin processing
        var autoClosePromise = autoCloseExecutables.pop();
        recursiveWhen(autoClosePromise);

        // Results
        $.when(wrapper).then(function (result) {

            dictionary.$elements.btnClose.removeClass('disabled');
            dictionary.$elements.btnContinue.removeClass('disabled');

            var isSuccessful = $('.exception', $interactions).length === 0;
            if (isSuccessful) {

                // Raise Event
                $(that).trigger('InteractionsSuccessful', [{ $interactions: $interactions }]);
                return;
            }

            // Raise Event
            // Currently, only 1 can exist at-a-time
            var $exception = $('.exception', $interactions);
            $(that).trigger('InteractionFailed', [{ $interaction: $exception }]);
        });
    }
    catch (exception) {
        app.utils.logger.error(exception);
        dictionary.$elements.btnClose.removeClass('disabled');
        dictionary.$elements.btnContinue.removeClass('disabled');
    }
}
```